# How to add local images to Excel with Office Scripts

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

Hi I am trying to replace Excel cells containing the image filepath with the actual images themselves.

One of the samples in Office Scripts demonstrate how images with an online URL can be inserted, but does not say anything for local files.

I have tried absolute and relative paths as shown below, but both do not work.

```
const link = "../sample.jpg"
```

I have linked the mentioned article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/add-image-to-workbook#sample-code-add-an-image-from-a-url-to-a-workbook

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This inserts image with top left corner at active cell:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("PATH_TO_IMAGE\image.jpg")
```

Comment: Hi Tony, is this VBA or Office Script?

Comment: Oops, must've got confused. My bad.